# access NEST Cameras using Smart device management API by google

Tags: nest, nest-device-access

I am trying to access the NEST camera devices using SDM API. to perform this I have followed the steps mentioned here "https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize#link_your_account".

So far I am able to get the authorization code and got the access token also, but when I am trying to get the devices using the access token, it is showing me blank.
the google documents are also not so much helpful and the process of registering and accessing is cumbersome.
If anybody has done that, please share your thoughts. I really need some help on it.

thank you in advance.
[image: result from the API]

Answer (score 1):

When you were authorizing your app you should have seen a dialog where you authorize the scopes and choose which Nest devices you want to have access to.  If you didn't choose any devices this is what would happen.